# Freemake Video Converter - Why do I see CUDA message?

Tags: windows-xp, video, graphics-card, conversion, video-conversion

When I start Freemake Video Converter 2.1.5.0 (downloadable from http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/), I see this message:

"Driver update required

Accelerate video encoding and lower CPU usage by enabling CUDA on your PC. Just update the graphics card driver
Your Card: NVIDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405"

However, I have installed the latest version 275.33 NVIDIA driver downloaded from their site (and restarted), but I still see this message.

Could you please advise why I still see this message when the latest drivers are installed (and functioning correctly to the best of my knowledge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say badly programmed application. Your video card doesn't support CUDA and the application should say so instead of misleading you. New versions of CUDA get published with new drivers, and when application can't detect CUDA support, the most obvious way to sole the problem is to get new drivers that will update CUDA to version which application needs. It seems that they forgot the option of not having a video card which supports CUDA.

If you really need CUDA, [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html)'s a list of supported video cards. As you can see it works only on 8000 series and newer.